# Proving the Tautology $\vdash (p\rightarrow q)\vee(q\rightarrow r)$

Tags: logic

I am having difficulty with $\vdash (p\rightarrow q)\vee(q\rightarrow r)$.
My idea to solve this was to first assume p, somehow find q, write that $p\rightarrow q$ and then write $\vee i$ for the second part of the statement. I know that just assuming p is not enough to solve this, so I need to make one of two more assumptions about q and r. If I just assume q to be true, then I will get that $q \rightarrow q $, which I don't want. Below is the best I could do.

$ 1. \space p$ assumption

$ 2. \space q$ assumption

$ 3. \space q \rightarrow q \rightarrow i \space 2$

$ 4. \space p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow q) \space \rightarrow i \space 1, \space 2-3$

$ 5. \space (p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow q)) \space \vee   (q \rightarrow r) \space \vee i \space 4 $

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your proof is getting nowhere ...  Always focus on the *main* connective of what you are trying to prove.  In this case, that is a $\lor$. So, even though there are $\rightarrow$'s appearing in the formula, since they are not the main connective, you should not try to do a conditional proof.

HINT

When what you are trying to prove is a disjunction (i.e when the main conective is a $\lor$), there are typically 3 strategies:

1. If you are lucky, you may be able to get to one of the disjuncts .. no such luck here!
2. If you have a disjunction to work with, then set up a proof by cases ($\lor$ Elim) on that disjunction ... unless you have the Law of Excluded Middle to work with, you have no disjunction to work with!
3. Try a proof by contradiction. ... Yes, do this by a proof by contradiction!

Comment: I was told by my friend that it would be simple to do this using the Law of Excluded Middle. My only issue is I don't know how to choose which variable I should use.

Comment: @DrJessop Well, out of $p$, $q$, and $r$, is there one that seems to be 'special'?

Answer (score 0):

$\neg P\vee Q$ is the same as $P\to Q$.

$(p\to q)\vee (q\to r)\equiv(\neg p\vee q)\vee(\neg q\vee r)\equiv\neg p\vee(q\vee \neg q)\vee r\equiv \neg p\vee T\vee r\equiv T$.

This is using the Law of the Excluded Middle ($q\vee \neg q\equiv T$).

Without knowing what kind of deduction system you are using, this may or may not count as a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $q\equiv T$.  Then $(p\rightarrow q)\equiv T$.

Assume that $\neg q\equiv T$.  Then $(q\rightarrow r)\equiv T$.

So you can prove it with the Law of the Excluded Middle.